# Defining a list of tuples with optional first and last elements

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to model some data in TypeScript that looks like this:

```js
// Sometimes we lookup the min/max dynamically, so we have keywords for them.
const intervalA: NumericInterval = [['$min', 3], [3, 5], [5, '$max']];

// Other times, we know the min/max and provide them inline
const intervalB: NumericInterval = [[0, 3], [3, 5], [5, 7]];
```

I've tried to define `NumericInterval` as:

```js
type MinInterval = ['$min', number];
type MaxInterval = [number, '$max'];
type Interval = [number, number];
type NumericInterval = [MinInterval?, ...Interval[], MaxInterval?];
```

However, TypeScript is doesn't like it because `A rest element must be last in a tuple`.

Is there a better way to express this schema?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to represent this type directly as far as I know.  It is a subtype of the concrete type `Array<["$min" | number, number | "$max"]>`, which is too wide and allows things like `[[2, "$max"],[4, "$max"],["$min", 6]]`.

You *can* use [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), and [conditional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) types to represent the desired shape as a constraint on array types, but it's fairly ugly/tedious/complex and you'd have to make anything which produces or accepts the type be generic.  I might as well show one way to do it, without much explanation (I can always edit in a more thorough explanation if you actually care about it or want to use this solution):

```
// get the tail of a tuple: Tail<[1,2,3]> is [2,3]
type Tail<L extends any[]> = ((...x: L) => any) extends
    ((h: any, ...t: infer T) => any) ? T : never;

// verify that T is a valid NumericInterval
type VerifyNumericInterval<T> = T extends Array<any> ?
    { [K in keyof T]: [
        K extends '0' ? "$min" | number : number,
        K extends keyof Tail<T> ? number : number | "$max"
    ] } : Array<["$min" | number, number | "$max"]>

// helper function to ensure parameter is a valid NumericInterval
const asNumericInteral = <T extends any[] | [any]>(
    numericInterval: T & VerifyNumericInterval<T>
): T => numericInterval;
```

And let's test it:

```
asNumericInteral([]); // okay, zero length tuple
asNumericInteral([[1, 2]]); // okay
asNumericInteral([["$min", 2]]); // okay
asNumericInteral([[1, "$max"]]); // okay
asNumericInteral([["$min", "$max"]]); // okay, not sure if you want it to be
asNumericInteral([["$max", 2]]); // error!
//                 ~~~~~~ <-- string not assignable to never
asNumericInteral([[1, 2], [3, "$max"]]); // okay
asNumericInteral([["$min", 2], [3, "$max"]]); // okay
asNumericInteral([["$min", 2], [3, "$max"], [5, 6]]); // error!
//                                 ~~~~~~ <-- string not assignable to number
```

This all behaves as I'd expect for that type.  By the way, this will only be of use for callers of functions that expect `NumericInterval` types.  Inside implementations that have a value of generic type `T & VerifyNumericInterval<T>` you will likely have to deal with edge cases yourself.  There's little chance that the compiler would be able to reason about an unresolved generic type well enough to notice, say, the following:

```
function hmm<T>(numInt: T & VerifyNumericInterval<T>) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numInt.length; i++) { // okay, numInt is known to be aray
        const interval = numInt[i]; // interval is type [number | "$min", "$max" | number]
        if (i !== 0) { // can't be "$min", right?
            interval[0].toFixed(); // error?! 
            // but it has to be a number, why doesn't the compiler know it?!
        }

        // manually check
        if ((i !== 0) && (typeof interval[0] === "number")) {
            interval[0].toFixed(); // okay now
        } 
    }
}
```

In that function *you* know that except for `i === 0`, `numInt[i]` is a pair where the first element is definitely a `number`.  But the compiler can't figure it out, so you have to walk it through extra checks (or use type assertions) to help it.

All right, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider representing it as a Map like this:

```
type min = "$min" | number;
type max = "$max" | number;

const NI = new Map<min, max>([["$min", 3], [2,3], [1,2], [5, "$max"]]);

console.log([...NI]);
```

Alternatively you could make your array one level deeper so allow for middle spread in the tuple.

```
type all = [MinInterval[], Interval[], MaxInterval[]];

const min: MinInterval = ["$min", 3];
const max: MaxInterval = [5, "$max"];
const interval: Interval[] = [[5, 3], [3, 4]];
const a: all = [[min], [...interval], [max]];

console.log(a.flat(1));
```